# Why some of my cronjobs were never executed?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have the following cronjobs in my crontab:

```
0  22 *   *    1-6 /root/sbin/mysqlbackup --conf-dir=/root/etc/backup --source=MonitoringServer --set-name=$(date +"\%A")                                             2>&1 | mail -s "Backup /MonitoringServer" it@example.com
0  22 *   *    0   [ "`date +\%d`" -gt 7 ] && /root/sbin/mysqlbackup --conf-dir=/root/etc/backup --source=MonitoringServer --set-name=Woche$((($(date +\%-d)-1)/7+1)) 2>&1 | mail -s "Backup /MonitoringServer" it@example.com
0  22 *   2-12 0   [ "`date +\%d`" -lt 8 ] && /root/sbin/mysqlbackup --conf-dir=/root/etc/backup --source=MonitoringServer --set-name=$(date +"\%B")                  2>&1 | mail -s "Backup /MonitoringServer" it@example.com
0  22 *   1    0   [ "`date +\%d`" -lt 8 ] && /root/sbin/mysqlbackup --conf-dir=/root/etc/backup --source=MonitoringServer --set-name=$(date +"\%Y")                  2>&1 | mail -s "Backup /MonitoringServer" it@example.com
```

Whereas the first line should generate the backup every monday till saturday (works).
The second line should generate a backup every sunday using the week of month as name, except for the first week (works).
The third line should be executed every first sunday of the months february till december (does not work).
The last line should be executed every first sunday of a year (unknown if called).

Everything seems right for me. Can anybody tell me why the third line does not work?

update

```
✓ root@mirror ~$  echo $(date +"%B");
September
✓ root@mirror ~$  [ "`date +%d`" -lt 8 ] && echo "Test"
Test
✓ root@mirror ~$  echo "`date +%d`"
02
```

update

no mail was sent on august, 7th (firs sunday of last month). means if the job would have been executed there had to be at least an empty mail?

update

```
/root/sbin/mysqlbackup --conf-dir=/root/etc/backup --source=MonitoringServer --set-name=$(date +"\%B")
```

performs well using a sh shell (which is used by cron by default) and using a bash shell (which is configured at the beginning of the crontab).

```
19 8 * 2-12 5 [ "`date +\%d`" -lt 8 ] && echo $(date +"\%B") 2>&1 | mail -s "Backup /MonitoringServer" it@example.com
```

performed well, too. Mail recieved containing the month's name.

Comment: You have a good level of detail, but you should still go through *every* troubleshooting step in the [Stack Overflow `crontab` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info). These questions are usually off-topic here, anyway, as they relate to a system administration tool, not to programming.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is **correct**. `cron` must have triggered execution for line 3 on Aug 7.

And yes, **you should have received an email on Aug 07**, independent of outcome (and even existence) of the backup script.

If you did not not receive an email, possible reasons are:

- `cron` was down (or the entire machine was)
- you configured a bad SHELL for `cron`
- the mail service was down.

I'd check the syslogs for cron execution, email submission, and for execution of `mysqlbackup`.

Comment: logs from last month are purged. will have to wait till sunday

Comment: You may want to setup some test entries, e.g., `0  10 *   2-12 5   [ "\`date +\%d\`" -lt 8 ] && true| mail -s "Backup /MonitoringServer" yourmail@example.com`, so you can try right away. Did the same myself to reproduce your problem, that's why I'm sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: test entry performed well, syslog shows the command. however the crontab entries exist since may, and none of the monthly jobs were executed

Comment: Maybe your systems are down on Sundays...?

Comment: meanwhile I believe this, too .... but no. other cronjobs which perform daily were executed

Comment: sometimes I think this debian box hates me ;-)

Comment: Instead of writing the whole line in cron, perhaps you be better of putting it all in a script and just referring to the script in the cron, just for testing purposes. Then in the script, write to a log file after each item, so you know where it goes wrong and you then also know your cron is probebly not the problem.

Comment: Writing to a log file doesn't need to be explicit. Put `exec 2>>/path/to/log.txt; set -x`  in your script after the shebang, and there you are, you have a detailed log of every action taken.